# NSolve syntax for region

Tags: equation-solving, regions

I am trying to solve these simultaneous system of equations only in a specified rectangle going from -100<x<100 and -100<y<100. But I think I am making a syntax error and hence I m not getting the specified results. I am not that familiar with Mathematica solving so it could be something else as well so any help will be appreciated.

```
 p1 = 6.335324557411202
p2 = 0.022176585993375648
p3 = 0.07021431437741502
p4 = 19.398896396198538
p5 = 6.283185307179586
a = 0.325
Ly = 200
NSolve[x*(2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*p1*p2*Exp[-p2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]^2] - 
       p3)/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) == 
   0 && (0.5*(Cot[\[Pi]*(2*a + y)/(2*Ly) + \[Pi]/2] - 
        Cot[\[Pi]*(2*a - y)/(2*Ly) + \[Pi]/2])*\[Pi]/(2*Ly) + 
     y*(p3 - 2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]*p1*p2*
          Exp[-p2*Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]^2])/(Sqrt[x^2 + y^2])) == 0 , -100 <
   x < 100, -100 < y < 100, {x, y}, Reals]
```

The error that it throws is

```
Requested precision \!\(\*TemplateBox[{},\"Reals\"]\) is not a \
machine-sized real number between $MinPrecision and $MaxPrecision
``
```

Comment: Try `&& -100 < x < 100 && -100 < y < 100`, not `, -100 < x < 100, -100 < y < 100`

Comment: Nah it just returns the input already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

`ContourPlot` shows the real solutions

```
    eqn = {1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
      x (-0.07021431437741502` + 
       0.28099173968674807` E^(-0.022176585993375648` (x^2 + y^2))
         Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) == 0, 
   1/Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]
       y (0.07021431437741502` - 
        0.28099173968674807` E^(-0.022176585993375648` (x^2 + y^2))
          Sqrt[x^2 + y^2]) + 
     0.003926990816987242` (Tan[1/400 \[Pi] (0.65` - y)] - 
        Tan[1/400 \[Pi] (0.65` + y)]) == 0} ;



    ContourPlot [Evaluate[eqn], {x, -15 , 15 }, {y, -15 , 
  15 }, PlotPoints -> 50, ContourStyle -> {Blue, {Dashed, Red}}]
```

[image]

The solution might be found on two circles:

small circle:

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] /. NMinimize[{1, Append[eqn, x^2 + y^2 < 1 ]}, {x, y}][[2]]
(*radius 0.250173 *)
```

large circle:

```
Sqrt[x^2 + y^2] /. NMinimize[{1, Append[eqn, x^2 + y^2 > 1 ]}, {x, y}][[2]]
(*radius 13.4229 *)
```